# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:272) while accessing JAX-WS services

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

I'm getting the following exception while implementing JAX-WS services in a Java EE 7 application.

```
Warning:   Internal Server error: /Test-war/Test.xhtml
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The exception message appears to be very specific to GlassFish Server (I'm using 4.1).

---

The test scenario:

A CDI managed bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped    
public class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private String test;
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

    public TestManagedBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        TestBean_Service testBean_Service=new TestBean_Service();
        TestBean testBean = testBean_Service.getTestBeanPort();
        System.out.println("testBean sum = "+testBean.getSum(5, 10));
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
}
```

The member variable `test` is just useless. It is taken only for the purpose of testing.

In an XHTML page, just access this `test` field like so,

```
<h:outputText value="#{testManagedBean.test}"/>
```

so that the bean's method marked by `@PostConstruct` can be invoked.

The exception occurs, when entering an appropriate URL in the browser's address bar.

---

The `testBean.getSum(int, int)` is a remote EJB method which is successfully invoked, when the bean is changed to a singleton EJB just for reasons of testing like so,

```
import client.web.services.TestBean;
import client.web.services.TestBean_Service;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;

@Startup
@Singleton
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class TestManagedBean
{
    public TestManagedBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        TestBean_Service testBean_Service=new TestBean_Service();
        TestBean testBean = testBean_Service.getTestBeanPort();
        System.out.println("testBean sum = "+testBean.getSum(5, 10));
    }
}
```

In this case, the the proxy method `getSum(int, int)` which is actually available in the associated remote EJB is successfully invoked and it returns the sum of the two parameters supplied through it.

What makes GlassFish think about the `java.lang.NullPointerException`, when the service is accessed via an XHTML page?

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug in GlassFish 4.1 affecting the `grizzly-kernel` component in the server - the GlassFish Grizzly Embedded Server serving HTTP requests. This requires replacing the `nucleus-grizzly-all.jar` jar file in GlassFish server (4.1)  as suggested [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21118?focusedCommentId=381897&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-381897) under `${glassfishHome}/glassfish/modules` (do not forget to clear `osgi-cache` under `#{glassfishHome}/glassfish/domains/yourDomain` before starting/restarting the server).

I visited that link prior to this post but its status was "resolved" according to GlassFish Server 4.1 that made me think something different.

Please note : Someone already posted the same answer a few hours ago but the answer was deleted perhaps by trusted users considering a link-only answer. Despite the fact that it is a link-only answer but in this case, there is no way to get around the issue other than replacing the new jar in the server and even the jar was provided after this question was asked on November 19, 2014. I hope this answer will not be deleted.

Comment: I don't get with osgi-cache, I didn't found anything like that, but instead of that, it works :-)

Comment: The `felix` folder under `osgi-cache` that contains several bundles is usually required to clear, when we make some changes to modules in the server to reflect those changes (the `felix` folder is generally located at (regarding windows its full path looks like) - `C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache`. I do not install GlassFish in `Program Files`, since it requires administrator privileges). The `felix` folder is automatically created, when the server is started/restarted.

Comment: I generally also delete the `generated` folder usually located at `C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated` (on windows) that may sometimes introduce some incompatibilities among the modules.