# NullPointerException at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:272) in a glassfish cluster

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

I'm having a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886584/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-org-apache-catalina-connector-coyoteadapter-se/27074776#27074776?newreg=0493191785d84e07b1063f9f3ac56330) question, but in a multiple machine cluster environment. If I deploy my application to the server (as in a single node) my pages work perfectly. However, when I use the same exact file to deploy to my cluster I start getting the title error!

My cluster is working fine for other applications that I have, so I don't think it's something related to it.

I tried to update the nucleus-grizzly-all.jar, as well as deleting the osgi-cache and generated folders, in all nodes but I'm still getting the error. Any help or clue would be a life saver.

Comment: Is GlassFish 4.1 commercially available? It is already declared as a commercially [dead server](http://blog.arungupta.me/glassfish-commercial-is-dead-wildfly-and-jboss-eap-to-rescue/) and merely intended to be used as a reference to Java EE 7. "*Oracle will no longer release future major releases of Oracle GlassFish Server with commercial support – specifically Oracle GlassFish Server 4.x with commercial Java EE 7 support will not be released.*"

Comment: "*You can use GlassFish as a reference to ensure your code is using pure Java EE 7 APIs but any production deployments should seriously think twice before considering it as a choice of application server.*"